# Can not telnet to 25 port

Tags: telnet

I can not connect any mail server using telnet through 25 port. I can connect with any web-server using 80 port.So i searched for my open port

```
sudo nmap -sS -p 20-2550 localhost
```

It shows:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000060s latency).
Not shown: 2524 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
23/tcp  open  telnet
80/tcp  open  http
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp open  ipp
902/tcp open  iss-realsecure
```

No 25 port open. When i try to connect with mail-server it just timeout. How could i enable telnet 25 port.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you trying to do??? telnet port seems ok, do you want to change it?

Comment: Did you install a mail server? There is no mail server installed by default, so nothing is listening on port 25 of localhost.

Comment: i am trying to connect gmail mail-server or hotmail mail-server. Finding mail-server address using nslookup -q=mx hotmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 25 is used for SMTP, for *sending* mails which is different from *receiving* mails using POP3 or IMAP. To check if something is listening on port 25, use `sudo netstat -tunlp` (**T**CP, **U**DP, **n**umeric addresses, **l**istening services, show **p**rograms (for which you need `sudo`)). If the output is large, try filtering it by appending `| grep :25` so it becomes `sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :25`.

If you're trying to telnet to external servers or network IP's, be sure that the router or your provider does not block port 25. Here, the Dutch ISP KPN blocks port 25 which will make your requests go into `/dev/null` (hence the timeout).

Comment: nothing is listening on 25 port. I am using Banglalion Wimax.

Comment: A quick Google make me believe that your provider sucks and that blocking port 25 is one of their restrictions.